# How can I translate canvas after rotation to keep a rectangle in the center of another in android?

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, transformation

I want to be able to draw text and rectangles to the canvas after I have rotated them along their center.  So I am making a test case where I have a blue square that does not get rotated, and a red square that should be rotated.  THey are the same size, and should share the same center "pivot point".  I have the following code:

```
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    p.setAlpha(200);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(100,100,300,300), p);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(45,250,250);// 250,250 is the center of the blue rectangle
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setAlpha(100);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(100,100,300,300), p);
    canvas.restore();
```

It gives me a result close to what I want, but I am missing some math, because it looks like the canvas also needs a translation applied.  Here is the result:
[image: result]

What I am missing so that I can rotate the red rectangle along the center of the blue one, and they end up sharing the same center point like this:
[image: desired]

Comment: Looks like the center of the rectangle is `(200,200)`! How did you come up with 250?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center of the blue rectangle is wrong.

`center(x,y) = (left + (width/2), top + (height/2))`

Note: `width = 200, height = 200` so, `center(x,y) = (200,200)`

Change to this, and it works:

```
canvas.rotate(45,200,200);// 200,200 is the center of the blue rectangle
```

Comment: I completely forgot that the 300,300 are right and bottom, not width and height.  Thank you for the answer!  I am glad it was such a simple mistake.